# bs4 python extracting value from <span></span> to .csv printing the same result over and over

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have managed to build a very primitive program to scrape vehicle data from pistonheads and print it to a `.csv` file with the link, make, model and am working on getting the price which is where I am encountering a problem.

I want to scrape the prices to the fourth column in my `.csv` file (`Price`) and to correctly print the prices from each vehicle on the website.

I am only getting it to print the price from one vehicle and repeat it again and again next to each vehicle in the `.csv` file.

I have tried `soup.findAll` and `soup.find_all` to see whether parsing through multiple  elements would work but this is just creating a bigger mess.

Might someone be able to help?

I am also trying to scrape the image src and would like to print that on another column (5) called `images`.

```
import csv ; import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('pistonheads.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Link", "Make", "Model", "Price"])

url = 'https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&Page=1&ResultsPerPage=100'

get_url = requests.get(url)

get_text = get_url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, 'html.parser')

car_link = soup.find_all('div', 'listing-headline', 'price')

for div in car_link:
   links = div.findAll('a')
      for a in links:
      link = ("https://www.pistonheads.com" + a['href'])
      make = (a['href'].split('/')[-4])
      model = (a['href'].split('/')[-3])
      price = soup.find('span')
      writer.writerow([link, make, model, price])
      print(link, make, model, price)
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
import csv, requests, re
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&ResultsPerPage=100').text, 'html.parser')
def extract_details(_s:soup) -> list:
  _link = _s.find('a', {'href':re.compile('/classifieds/used\-cars/')})['href']
  _, _, make, model, *_ = _link[1:].split('/')
  price, img = _s.find('div', {'class':'price'}).text, [i['src'] for i in _s.find_all('img')]
  return [_link, make, model, price, 'N/A' if not img else img[0]]

with open('filename.csv', 'w') as f:
  _listings = [extract_details(i) for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'ad-listing'}) if i.find('div', {'class':'price'})]
  write = csv.writer(f)
  write.writerows([['make', 'model', 'price', 'img'], *_listings])
```

Comment: I would also probably do something such as `'N/A' if not price else price`. Also I think the OP wants the listing link included, anyway .. +1

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because of `price = soup.find('span')`

`.find()` will grab the first element it finds. And you have it looking into your `soup` object. But where you want it to look, is within your `a`, because that's what you are looping through with `for a in links:`

I also add `.text` as I am assuming you just want the text, not the whole tag element. Ie `price = a.find('span').text`

```
import csv ; import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

outfile = open('pistonheads.csv','w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["Link", "Make", "Model", "Price", 'Images'])

url = 'https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&Page=1&ResultsPerPage=100'

get_url = requests.get(url)

get_text = get_url.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, 'html.parser')

car_link = soup.find_all('div', 'listing-headline', 'price')

for div in car_link:
   links = div.findAll('a')
   for a in links:
      link = ("https://www.pistonheads.com" + a['href'])
      make = (a['href'].split('/')[-4])
      model = (a['href'].split('/')[-3])
      price = a.find('span').text
      image_link = a.parent.parent.find('img')['src']
      image = link + image_link
      writer.writerow([link, make, model, price, image])
      print(link, make, model, price, image)



outfile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly, I see what I was doing wrong now. Thanks again!